# Can the natural logarithm, $\ln$, have an exponent?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function

$$f(x)=\ln^3(x^2+\tan(3x))$$

This is a question from a past final exam. I need to derive this function and I have one simple question. Is it possible for that natural log to have its own exponent. How would I even go about deriving this problem seeing as how $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(x)) = \frac{1}{x}$ ?

Comment: Yes it's possible, you just use the chain rule several times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this can be rewritten as $(\ln(x^2+\tan(3x)))^3$ just like how trig functions like $\sin^2(x)$ are analogous to saying $(\sin(x))^2$

Comment: oh gosh, I thought it might be something like that. It's confusing since not once has my teacher or the textbook shown it like that .